# How to define Meta tags on Views?

Tags: 7, views, meta-tags

Is there any module or some configuration that I can define the meta tags for the views page display in drupal 7 using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) 3.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Meta tags quick](http://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) module allows you to specify Meta tags based on path for your views. If you enable path-based meta tags, you will see 'Edit meta tags' link on the views page (important - not in the views edit screen!).

Comment: Nice, I was using the 1.9 version. This feature for tagging a page based on the url is only on 2.0 beta version. Thanks.

Comment: For me it was a "Path-Based Metatags" titled tab on the page itself (frontend). Also had to make sure `render($tabs)` was printed in `page.tpl.php`.

Answer (score 13):

The [Metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) module has views integration from the box since 7.x-1.0-beta2.

Install the metatags_views submodule and you'll get metatag options in the views UI for any views page display (Paul Querol's comment below).

Comment: Surprised this answer isn't getting more love... If you're using the metatags module then just install the metatags_views submodule and you'll get metatag options in the views UI for any views page display.

Comment: Agree. But the answer above was in 2011. There was no metatags_views submodule at that time. You can add the text about metatags_views submodule into my answer if you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the "Path-Based Metatags" as mentioned earlier you could make the default [metatags_quick](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) fields added to the term itself work as desired with the following approach. Here is an example of how I did it with robots and the help of [`drupal_add_html_head()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK()
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // if this is a term page and not being edited
  if (arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2)) && is_null(arg(3))) {
    // if this is a Views page
    $view = (array)views_get_page_view();
    if (!empty($view)) {
      // if metatags_quick robots are set
      $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
      if (isset($term->meta_robots) && !empty($term->meta_robots[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['metatags_quick']))

      $element = array(
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
          'name' => $term->meta_robots[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['meta_name'],
          'content' => $term->meta_robots[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['metatags_quick']
        ),
      );
      drupal_add_html_head($element, 'MYMODULE');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most straight forward solution is to add the view as a block inside a node, and then use module like [Metatag](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) to place metatags on the node.

Avoids the views integration issue. Also provides benefit of breadcrumbs, menus, pathauto, etc. all easier to set up when page is a node rather than a view.

Comment: Downvote as I don't see this as being feasible in many cases, such as a site which has a few contextual arguments on a view, and the meta needs to differ for different view arguments.