# no-indexing a views page

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Im using D7 and views 3 and I cant seem to find a solid answer on how to do this or if its possible but I created a page in views and I wanted to no-index the page, I dont see any options in views to do it so im wondering if this is possible and if so how can I go about doing this.

Any help is appreciated it.

EDIT**

Here is a function I managed to come up with however it something is making it not work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
function noindex_taxonomy(&$head_elements) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(2) == 104 || arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(2) == 103 || arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(2) == 108) {
    $head_elements['noindex'] = array(
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'name' => 'robots',
        'content' => 'noindex',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achiveve this by putting my function into my template.tpl.php file

```
function loans_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {

/*Url inside the view*/ $siteurls = drupal_get_path_alias();

if (arg(0)== 'taxonomy' && $siteurls == 'taxonomy/term/104/latest') {
    $head_elements['noindex'] = array(
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'name' => 'robots',
        'content' => 'noindex',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not any option in views module to add metatags. but you can add metatags to any url of your site by other drupal metatag modules.
See [How to define Meta tags on Views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/meta-tags-on-views-in-drupal-7).

Comment: Yeah I tried using that but its throwing off errors on my site.