# Metatags for Views page?

Tags: views, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meta tags on Views in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/meta-tags-on-views-in-drupal-7)

Tried metatags module, it is great, but can only set meta for Content, Tax, Front, etc, not for Views.

How to set metatags info for Views page? programmatically or by module

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 
[Meta tags quick](http://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick)
The Meta tags quick module allows you to specify Meta tags based on path for your views

Interesting article on Meta tag generation [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/18941)