# How can I add meta tags for pages created with views in Drupal 8?

Tags: views, 8, meta-tags

I need to add meta tags for pages created using views in Drupal 8, I tried to use [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module. but it seems like there is no views integration on D8 version of this module. I also tried to install [Meta tags Quick](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) but it's not working!

is there any other alternatives? please advice.

Edit: I've already seen the answers for [this previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/meta-tags-on-views-in-drupal-7) but all of them are recommending using the modules that I've already tried: *Metatag* currently doesn't support adding meta tags to pages created with views, and *Meta tags quick* doesn't work with current Drupal version 8.0.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meta tags on Views in Drupal 7](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/meta-tags-on-views-in-drupal-7)

Comment: This question is about Drupal 8, thus not duplicate.

Comment: OP asked [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36235842/1591669) on [so].

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is still in development, one option is to configure the View as a block, then insert that block on a Page.  This won't work for all scenarios, but is a (poor) alternative.